# Are there any websites that will emulate your webservice?

Tags: angularjs, web-services, rest, emulation

I'm writing an Angular app, and I'd like to test actual ajax ($http) functionality without having to write a backend webservice or having to install a Node/Apache server on each of my dev boxes to emulate this functionality.

I seem to remember there was a website that would allow you to describe your API and the expected output when you call one of the endpoints, and then it would give you a URL you could plug into your app to test with.

Does such a site exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[InstantAPI](https://www.instantapi.co/) looks like it might do the job. It isn't free, but it looks pretty reasonable (from $50 per year for a cloud solution).

Another idea might be to create stubs for each of your end-points and use the auto-respond feature of [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to return the stubs when you request the end-points.

Comment: Thanks, neither are exactly what I was looking for. It may be a cool idea to build into a site one day though!

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin available which can handle this:

http://appendto.com/2010/07/mock-your-ajax-requests-with-mockjax-for-rapid-development/